# ideal aws instance type for neo4j database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

neo4j 3.2 version is installed aws Linux ec2 instance. I am checking for the ideal instance type.

There are different projects persisted in the neo4j graph and each project can have around 50k nodes, a million relationships, and around 100k properties. A single save operation can have up to 25k nodes, 75k relations, and 10k properties. i tried out i2,d2,r largest instance type. everything is taking almost a minute or more for every "save" operation. In my windows operating system, max time it takes is 20 seconds. 
what would be the ideal instance type in this scenario?

and i also doubt whether it has something to do with the neo4j.conf file. there are so many jvm paramaters mentioned in neo4j.conf in Linux aws. none of them are specified in my windows system.

```
#*****************************************************************
# Neo4j configuration
#
# For more details and a complete list of settings, please see
# https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/configuration-settings/
#*****************************************************************

# The name of the database to mount
#dbms.active_database=graph.db

# Paths of directories in the installation.
dbms.directories.data=/var/lib/neo4j/data
dbms.directories.plugins=/var/lib/neo4j/plugins
dbms.directories.certificates=/var/lib/neo4j/certificates
dbms.directories.logs=/var/log/neo4j
dbms.directories.lib=/usr/share/neo4j/lib
dbms.directories.run=/var/run/neo4j

# This setting constrains all `LOAD CSV` import files to be under the `import` directory. Remove or comment it out to
# allow files to be loaded from anywhere in the filesystem; this introduces possible security problems. See the
# `LOAD CSV` section of the manual for details.
dbms.directories.import=/var/lib/neo4j/import

# Whether requests to Neo4j are authenticated.
# To disable authentication, uncomment this line
#dbms.security.auth_enabled=false

# Enable this to be able to upgrade a store from an older version.
#dbms.allow_upgrade=true

# Java Heap Size: by default the Java heap size is dynamically
# calculated based on available system resources.
# Uncomment these lines to set specific initial and maximum
# heap size.
# dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=512m
#dbms.memory.heap.max_size=512m

# The amount of memory to use for mapping the store files, in bytes (or
# kilobytes with the 'k' suffix, megabytes with 'm' and gigabytes with 'g').
# If Neo4j is running on a dedicated server, then it is generally recommended
# to leave about 2-4 gigabytes for the operating system, give the JVM enough
# heap to hold all your transaction state and query context, and then leave the
# rest for the page cache.
# The default page cache memory assumes the machine is dedicated to running
# Neo4j, and is heuristically set to 50% of RAM minus the max Java heap size.
#dbms.memory.pagecache.size=10g

#*****************************************************************
# Network connector configuration
#*****************************************************************

# With default configuration Neo4j only accepts local connections.
# To accept non-local connections, uncomment this line:
dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0

# You can also choose a specific network interface, and configure a non-default
# port for each connector, by setting their individual listen_address.

# The address at which this server can be reached by its clients. This may be the server's IP address or DNS name, or
# it may be the address of a reverse proxy which sits in front of the server. This setting may be overridden for
# individual connectors below.
#dbms.connectors.default_advertised_address=localhost

# You can also choose a specific advertised hostname or IP address, and
# configure an advertised port for each connector, by setting their
# individual advertised_address.

# Bolt connector
dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=OPTIONAL
#dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=:7687

# HTTP Connector. There must be exactly one HTTP connector.
dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.http.listen_address=:7474

# HTTPS Connector. There can be zero or one HTTPS connectors.
dbms.connector.https.enabled=true
#dbms.connector.https.listen_address=:7473

# Number of Neo4j worker threads.
#dbms.threads.worker_count=

#*****************************************************************
# SSL system configuration
#*****************************************************************

# Names of the SSL policies to be used for the respective components.

# The legacy policy is a special policy which is not defined in
# the policy configuration section, but rather derives from
# dbms.directories.certificates and associated files
# (by default: neo4j.key and neo4j.cert). Its use will be deprecated.

# The policies to be used for connectors.
#
# N.B: Note that a connector must be configured to support/require
#      SSL/TLS for the policy to actually be utilized.
#
# see: dbms.connector.*.tls_level

#bolt.ssl_policy=legacy
#https.ssl_policy=legacy

#*****************************************************************
# SSL policy configuration
#*****************************************************************

# Each policy is configured under a separate namespace, e.g.
#    dbms.ssl.policy.<policyname>.*
#
# The example settings below are for a new policy named 'default'.

# The base directory for cryptographic objects. Each policy will by
# default look for its associated objects (keys, certificates, ...)
# under the base directory.
#
# Every such setting can be overriden using a full path to
# the respective object, but every policy will by default look
# for cryptographic objects in its base location.
#
# Mandatory setting

#dbms.ssl.policy.default.base_directory=certificates/default

# Allows the generation of a fresh private key and a self-signed
# certificate if none are found in the expected locations. It is
# recommended to turn this off again after keys have been generated.
#
# Keys should in general be generated and distributed offline
# by a trusted certificate authority (CA) and not by utilizing
# this mode.

#dbms.ssl.policy.default.allow_key_generation=false

# Enabling this makes it so that this policy ignores the contents
# of the trusted_dir and simply resorts to trusting everything.
#
# Use of this mode is discouraged. It would offer encryption but no security.

#dbms.ssl.policy.default.trust_all=false

# The private key for the default SSL policy. By default a file
# named private.key is expected under the base directory of the policy.
# It is mandatory that a key can be found or generated.

#dbms.ssl.policy.default.private_key=

# The private key for the default SSL policy. By default a file
# named public.crt is expected under the base directory of the policy.
# It is mandatory that a certificate can be found or generated.

#dbms.ssl.policy.default.public_certificate=

# The certificates of trusted parties. By default a directory named
# 'trusted' is expected under the base directory of the policy. It is
# mandatory to create the directory so that it exists, because it cannot
# be auto-created (for security purposes).
#
# To enforce client authentication client_auth must be set to 'require'!

#dbms.ssl.policy.default.trusted_dir=

# Client authentication setting. Values: none, optional, require
# The default is to require client authentication.
#
# Servers are always authenticated unless explicitly overridden
# using the trust_all setting. In a mutual authentication setup this
# should be kept at the default of require and trusted certificates
# must be installed in the trusted_dir.

#dbms.ssl.policy.default.client_auth=require

# A comma-separated list of allowed TLS versions.
# By default TLSv1, TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 are allowed.

#dbms.ssl.policy.default.tls_versions=

# A comma-separated list of allowed ciphers.
# The default ciphers are the defaults of the JVM platform.

#dbms.ssl.policy.default.ciphers=

#*****************************************************************
# Logging configuration
#*****************************************************************

# To enable HTTP logging, uncomment this line
#dbms.logs.http.enabled=true

# Number of HTTP logs to keep.
#dbms.logs.http.rotation.keep_number=5

# Size of each HTTP log that is kept.
#dbms.logs.http.rotation.size=20m

# To enable GC Logging, uncomment this line
#dbms.logs.gc.enabled=true

# GC Logging Options
# see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/819-0084-10/pt_tuningjava.html#wp57013 for more information.
#dbms.logs.gc.options=-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintPromotionFailure -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution

# Number of GC logs to keep.
#dbms.logs.gc.rotation.keep_number=5

# Size of each GC log that is kept.
#dbms.logs.gc.rotation.size=20m

# Size threshold for rotation of the debug log. If set to zero then no rotation will occur. Accepts a binary suffix "k",
# "m" or "g".
#dbms.logs.debug.rotation.size=20m

# Maximum number of history files for the internal log.
#dbms.logs.debug.rotation.keep_number=7

#*****************************************************************
# Miscellaneous configuration
#*****************************************************************

# Enable this to specify a parser other than the default one.
#cypher.default_language_version=3.0

# Determines if Cypher will allow using file URLs when loading data using
# `LOAD CSV`. Setting this value to `false` will cause Neo4j to fail `LOAD CSV`
# clauses that load data from the file system.
#dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls=true

# Retention policy for transaction logs needed to perform recovery and backups.
dbms.tx_log.rotation.retention_policy=1 days

# Enable a remote shell server which Neo4j Shell clients can log in to.
#dbms.shell.enabled=true
# The network interface IP the shell will listen on (use 0.0.0.0 for all interfaces).
#dbms.shell.host=127.0.0.1
# The port the shell will listen on, default is 1337.
#dbms.shell.port=1337

# Only allow read operations from this Neo4j instance. This mode still requires
# write access to the directory for lock purposes.
#dbms.read_only=false

# Comma separated list of JAX-RS packages containing JAX-RS resources, one
# package name for each mountpoint. The listed package names will be loaded
# under the mountpoints specified. Uncomment this line to mount the
# org.neo4j.examples.server.unmanaged.HelloWorldResource.java from
# neo4j-server-examples under /examples/unmanaged, resulting in a final URL of
# http://localhost:7474/examples/unmanaged/helloworld/{nodeId}
#dbms.unmanaged_extension_classes=org.neo4j.examples.server.unmanaged=/examples/unmanaged

#********************************************************************
# JVM Parameters
#********************************************************************

# G1GC generally strikes a good balance between throughput and tail
# latency, without too much tuning.
dbms.jvm.additional=-XX:+UseG1GC

# Have common exceptions keep producing stack traces, so they can be
# debugged regardless of how often logs are rotated.
#dbms.jvm.additional=-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow

# Make sure that `initmemory` is not only allocated, but committed to
# the process, before starting the database. This reduces memory
# fragmentation, increasing the effectiveness of transparent huge
# pages. It also reduces the possibility of seeing performance drop
# due to heap-growing GC events, where a decrease in available page
# cache leads to an increase in mean IO response time.
# Try reducing the heap memory, if this flag degrades performance.
dbms.jvm.additional=-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch

# Trust that non-static final fields are really final.
# This allows more optimizations and improves overall performance.
# NOTE: Disable this if you use embedded mode, or have extensions or dependencies that may use reflection or
# serialization to change the value of final fields!
dbms.jvm.additional=-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
dbms.jvm.additional=-XX:+TrustFinalNonStaticFields

# Disable explicit garbage collection, which is occasionally invoked by the JDK itself.
dbms.jvm.additional=-XX:+DisableExplicitGC

# Remote JMX monitoring, uncomment and adjust the following lines as needed. Absolute paths to jmx.access and
# jmx.password files are required.
# Also make sure to update the jmx.access and jmx.password files with appropriate permission roles and passwords,
# the shipped configuration contains only a read only role called 'monitor' with password 'Neo4j'.
# For more details, see: http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html
# On Unix based systems the jmx.password file needs to be owned by the user that will run the server,
# and have permissions set to 0600.
# For details on setting these file permissions on Windows see:
#     http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/security-windows.html
#dbms.jvm.additional=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=3637
#dbms.jvm.additional=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true
#dbms.jvm.additional=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
#dbms.jvm.additional=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/absolute/path/to/conf/jmx.password
#dbms.jvm.additional=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/absolute/path/to/conf/jmx.access

# Some systems cannot discover host name automatically, and need this line configured:
#dbms.jvm.additional=-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$THE_NEO4J_SERVER_HOSTNAME

# Expand Diffie Hellman (DH) key size from default 1024 to 2048 for DH-RSA cipher suites used in server TLS handshakes.
# This is to protect the server from any potential passive eavesdropping.
dbms.jvm.additional=-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Windows NT/2000/XP Service Properties
#********************************************************************
# WARNING - Do not modify any of these properties when an application
#  using this configuration file has been installed as a service.
#  Please uninstall the service before modifying this section.  The
#  service can then be reinstalled.

# Name of the service
dbms.windows_service_name=neo4j

#********************************************************************
# Other Neo4j system properties
#********************************************************************
dbms.jvm.additional=-Dunsupported.dbms.udc.source=rpm
```

Comment: Can you specify your windows operating system machine's configuration, as well as the minimum system requirements for your project?

Comment: 64 bit 32GB RAM windows 7 intel core i7 processor. I think the issues mentioned has something to do with neo4j.conf. Are there any limitations placed on conf file by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally figured out.
For neo4j graph db, ubuntu OS they prefer. Regarding instance type,
one with SSD storage is preferable. So we can go with M3.2xlarge.

Remember to configure IOPS which will increase the throughput. set heap & cache memory if required.

[Expand EBS Volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html)

[Modify EBS volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-modify-volume.html?icmpid=docs_ec2_console)

Answer (score 1):

According to your specified configurations and the give [recommended system requirements in documentation  at the official neo4j site](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/requirements/) I would suggest these instances:

1) If your application is burstable in nature, I would recommend Burstable Performance Instances like **t2.xlarge**(16 GB RAM, Intel Xeon family processor, moderate Networking Performance) or **t2.2xlarge** (32 GB RAM, Intel Xeon family processor, moderate Networking Performance).

2) If your application is general purpose and requires high configuration I would recommend:

If cost is a concern- **m3.xlarge**(4 vCPU, 15 GB RAM, Intel Xeon E5-2670 v2, High Networking Performance, 2 x 40 SSD), **m3.2xlarge**(8 vCPU, 30 GB RAM, Intel Xeon E5-2670 v2, High Networking Performance, 2 x 80 SSD)

or

If you want the best and the latest generation of General Purpose Instances-  **m4.xlarge**(4 vCPU, 16 GB RAM, Intel Xeon E5-2676 v3, High Networking Performance, EBS Only storage), **m4.2xlarge**(8 vCPU, 32 GB RAM, Intel Xeon E5-2676 v3, High Networking Performance, EBS Only storage).

For more information on instance types you can refer [here](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/).